# How to build a Twitter app that posts a tweet every few hours

Tags: c#, twitter

I have a text file which has a bunch of tweets that I want to post every four hours or so.

So the app would run on AWS/Azure/somewhere where it would read the text file, read the next line, tweet it. Repeat every four hours

It has been a while since I coded but I can get back into it. I just dont know what sort of architecture I need to get started.

What should my tech stack look like to do something like this?

Comment: I don't do Twitter, and I realize that much of Twitter is bot-driven. However, have you checked the Termd of Service. I suspect that this might violate them

Answer (score 0):

A timer would be the first idea, of course. If something needs repition, it is usually the way to go. But there are at least half a dozen timers in .NET. Wich one to use really depensd what your application is.

With very short intervalls, some timers do run into issues with Events piling up faster then they can be processed. 
I wrote some basic rate-limiting code, that was intended to be run in a Dedicated thread - it might give you a starting point:

```
integer interval = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

With a intervall in the hours, something like the WindowsTask Sheduler and a programm with a very short runtime, might be worth looking into. But of course that one would not support going to very low intervalls later. It could also be somewhat hard to figure out of the operation is "running" smoothly or has had issues at any given time, if it only actually runs every so often.